# List the bookid and bookname of the books which has maximum cost per copy

Tags: sql, oracle

List the bookid and bookname of the books which has max cost per copy

`Manuscript` table

```
Bookid Authorid Bookname Genre numberofcopies Amount
```

---

here is what i tried.

```
select bookid, bookname 
from manuscript
where bookid=MAX(costpercopy.bookid)

select bookid,MAX(amount/Numberofcopies) AS costpercopy
from manuscript
group by bookid;
```

The costpercopy column doesn't exist and needs to be created by dividing amount by numberofcopies.
I need some help as where to put the subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query should help you:

```
SELECT BOOKID, BOOKNAME, (AMOUNT/NUMBEROFCOPIES) costpercopy FROM 
manuscript,
(
     SELECT MAX(AMOUNT/NUMBEROFCOPIES) REQVALUE FROM manuscript
) SUBTAB
WHERE (AMOUNT/NUMBEROFCOPIES) = REQVALUE;
```

Same query, using **join** would be like:

```
SELECT BOOKID, BOOKNAME, (AMOUNT/NUMBEROFCOPIES) costpercopy FROM manuscript INNER JOIN
(
SELECT MAX(AMOUNT/NUMBEROFCOPIES) REQVALUE FROM TESTDATA
) SUBTAB
ON (AMOUNT/NUMBEROFCOPIES) = REQVALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

This query orders all books by the costpercopy putting the most costly first:

```
select bookid, bookname
  from manuscript
  order by amount/numberofcopies desc;
```

Depending of your type of database you can add "fetch first 1 only" or "limit 1" to get only the first result.